# How to calculate an angle for a vector?

Tags: geometry, vectors

I have a vector *v* and I want to know its angle from "12 o'clock" (i.e. *u=(0,1)* going straight up). According to [the Internet](http://www.wikihow.com/Find-the-Angle-Between-Two-Vectors), I can use the formula as follows.

```
p = u * v = 0*v_x + 1*v_y = v_y
m = |u| = 1
n = |v| = sqrt(v_x^2 + v_y^2)
a = acos(p / m / n)
```

What doesn't make sense to me is that we apparently only consider the vertical dimension of the vector. I don't get it and it feels plain wrong. I must be missing something but I can't see what. Is the formula only applicable for certain angles (like the first quadrant or such)?

Comment: You are wrong to say that it only depends on the vertical dimension of the vector $v$. Note that $v_x$ is a hidden term in $n$, which you divide by to compute the angle.

Comment: On an unrelated note, the procedure you describe isn't exactly magical. It's a fact from vector algebra that $v\cdot w = |v||w|\cos\theta$, where $\theta$ is the angle between the two vectors. In this case you just solved for $\theta$. It might be worth reading a little about the dot product, since it's useful if you're doing any sort of geometry (even if you're primarily programming): https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product

Comment: Note that [`atan2(y,x)`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2) gives the counterclockwise angle between $(x,y)$ and the $x$ axis in radians. If 12 o'clock is towards positive $y$ axis, and 3 o'clock is towards positive $x$ axis, then the angle measured clockwise from 12 o'clock is `atan2(x,y)`. (If you don't care about the direction, then just check if the result is $\gt \pi$, and if so, substract it from $2 \pi$.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are wrong to say that it only depends on the vertical dimension of the vector $v_y$. Note that $v_x$ is a hidden term in $n$, which you divide by to compute the angle.

Computing angles between vectors amounts to solving the formula
$$v\cdot w = |v||w|\cos\theta,$$
where $\theta$ is the angle between the vectors. Again, you should [read a little about dot products](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product), since they come up all the time in geometry.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the dot product. If you have two vector $u$, $v$ then the dot product is $$u \cdot v = \| u \|\| v \| \cos{\theta},$$ where $\theta$ is the angle between the vectors. The dot product is also calculated from two vectors as $u \cdot v = x_1x_2+y_1y_2$. If we assume that the twelve o' clock (unit) vector has the coordinates x = 0, y = 1 your dot product will now be $u \cdot v = 0 \cdot x + 1\cdot y$. Substitute this into the above equation and solve for $\theta$ and you will get $\theta = \arccos{\frac{0\cdot x + 1\cdot y}{\sqrt{x^2 +y^2}}}$

Comment: I'm not entirely sure how that contributes to my question. It's precisely the same formula that I've linked to. The question isn't how to do it but rather what I'm missing while doing it. Turns out - nothing. I was right in my calculation. Please feel welcome to view the accepted answer.

Comment: Additionally, you are using the x coordinate of your vector when calculating the magnitude